# The Limit of an Integral Containing Exponentials

Tags: integration, limits, exponential-function, infinity, substitution

I am unsure how to show this.

Suppose $\delta(s)$ defined on $(-\infty , s_*)$ is increasing and satisfies $\lim _{s\rightarrow s_*} \delta = \lim _{s\rightarrow s_*} \frac{d \delta}{d s} = \infty$ then

$e^{-\delta (s)}\int _{s_0}^se^{\delta (s')}ds'\rightarrow 0$ as $s\rightarrow s_*$ for any $s_0<s_*$.

The hint is to rewrite the integration variables with respect to $\delta$. This means we need consider

$\lim _{\delta _s\rightarrow\infty}e^{-\delta}\int _{\delta _0}^{\delta _s}e^{\delta}(\frac{d\delta}{ds})^{-1}d\delta$ but I am unable to proceed further.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use De l'Hospital?
$$
\lim_{s \to s^*} \frac{e^{\delta(s)}}{e^{\delta(s)}\delta'(s)}=0.
$$